# Javascript how to accept multiple string inputs and check to see if it matches?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, forms

I'm making a game where an image is displayed above a input form and the user has to correctly identify the person in the image. Here is my form and Javascript

```
<form method="POST" action="form-handler" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
     <p>Input: <input type="text" size="32" name="inputfield"><input type="submit"></p>
</form>

 function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(form.inputfield.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Input is empty!");
      form.inputfield.focus();
      return false;
    }
    var re = /^[\w]+$/;

    if(!re.test(form.inputfield.value)) {
      alert("Error: Input contains invalid characters!");
      form.inputfield.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

I'm completely stuck on what I would do in Javascript. I want to make it so that there are multiple different answers someone can type, including first name only, last name only, nick names etc... and if a correct name version is entered, it will move on to the next image. If a submitted answer doesn't match the image, it will display "wrong answer" below the form. What do I need so that a display box won't pop up that said the answer is correct, but instead that it will go to the next image?

Comment: function checkForm(form)
  {
    // validation fails if the input is blank
    if(form.inputfield.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Input is empty!");
      form.inputfield.focus();
      return false;
    }

    // regular expression to match only alphanumeric characters and spaces
    var re = /^[\w]+$/;

    // validation fails if the input doesn't match our regular expression
    if(!re.test(form.inputfield.value)) {
      alert("Error: Input contains invalid characters!");
      form.inputfield.focus();
      return false;
    }
    // validation was successful
    return true;
  }

Comment: Add that to your question

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you're testing if the input provided starts and ends with one or more occurrences of [a-zA-Z0-9]...

you probably need to check with: `/(\w+)/i` that means any word and case insensitive (without whitespaces, ecc...)

***But if you're testing on a whitelist... you probably need to do the following:***

```
function isNapoleone(value) {
   var TRUE_IMAGENAME = 'Napoleone Bonaparte';
   return (TRUE_IMAGENAME.indexOf(value) > -1);
}
```